# Rounding datetime to quarter minutes

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a function to round a datetime to the nearest quarter hour. 
But is there a method to round down to the nearest quarter instead?

Example.

```
08:14:00 becomes 08:00:00
08:03:00 becomes 08:00:00
08:29:00 becomes 08:15:00 
08:55:00 becomes 08:45:00
```

This is what I have now to round to the nearest quarter.

```
(
@dt datetime
)
returns datetime
as
begin
declare @result datetime
declare @mm int
set @mm=datepart(minute,@dt)
set @result = dateadd(minute,-@mm + (round(@mm/cast(15 as float),0)*15) , @dt )

return @result
```

Comment: Why is your question tagged vb.net? I see no indication of VB's relevance here - if you're asking for a solution which you could use in *either* VB *or* SQL, you should be explicit in that.

Comment: Yes..  Sorry, you're right.  There's no relevance to VB..  I have remove the VB tag..  Thanks for pointing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using SQL Server:

```
select cast( 
         FLOOR( cast( GetDate() as float)*(24*4)) / (24*4) 
       as smalldatetime) AS "datetime_quarter"
```

The strategy is:

- Convert the date to a float number, `*24` to get number of hours, `*4` to get number of quarters
- Round down with `FLOOR`
- Convert back to number of days by `/(24*4)`
- Convert number of days to a datetime. `smalldatetime` is used to avoid float rounding issues.

This can easily be adjusted to use `ROUND`or `CEILING` instead; or to use other hour multiples instead of `4` (quarters).

Comment: THANK YOU!..  That have been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a procedure to get the current quarter upper and lower bound.

```
declare QUARTER_FLOOR datetime;
declare QUARTER_CEIL datetime;
declare CURRENT_DATETIME datetime;
declare CURRENT_MINUTE int;
// get current datetime without second and millisecond
SET CURRENT_DATETIME = dateformat(getdate(), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:NN:00.000');
set CURRENT_MINUTE = datepart(minute,CURRENT_DATETIME); // get current minute
// GET CURRENT QUARTER FLOOR
set QUARTER_FLOOR = dateadd(minute, -CURRENT_MINUTE + (round(CURRENT_MINUTE/cast(15 as float),0)*15) , CURRENT_DATETIME );
// GET CURRENT QUARTER FLOOR
set QUARTER_CEIL = dateadd(minute, ((round(CURRENT_MINUTE/cast(15 as float),0)+1)*15) - CURRENT_MINUTE , CURRENT_DATETIME );

 // RETURN
select  QUARTER_FLOOR, QUARTER_CEIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This method relies on integer division when we divide the month by 4. In principle it should be portable, subject of course to modifying the syntax of `dateadd()` / `date_add()` and `month()`/`year()`.

```
SELECT DATEADD(
  MONTH,
  3 * (
       MONTH( my_date ) / 4
       ),
  CONCAT(
    YEAR( my_date ),
    '0101' )
  ) AS my_date_rounded_to_quarter
```